# Execute Stored Procedure with OPENROWSET not working While connecting Azure VM to Azure DB via LinkedServer

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

My Objective is to run SSRS reports in Azure Database Service. But Azure Database Service not support SSRS reports hence need to configure SSRS in Azure Virtual Machine. So my SSRS reporting database in VM and datasource pointing to Azure Database.

Now in Store Procedure of Azure Database Service we used OPENROWSET which throw error. So after googling came to know that its can be handle via Linked Server which is created. Now am not able to understand out of two query one query is running while second throwing Error.

Success Query:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI','Server=AzureVM;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
                 'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON;
                  SELECT * FROM [MyAzureDbLinkedServer].[AzureDB].[dbo].CityTable') 
          As QueryData
```

Above Query fetching result correctly from Azure SQL DB Service.

Failure Query:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI','Server=AzureVM;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
                 'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON;
                  EXEC [MyAzureDbLinkedServer].[AzureDB].[dbo].PROC_LIST_SYS_ADMIN_CITY 102') 
          As ProcData
```

When i execute procedure it throwing error below:

```
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MyAzureDbLinkedServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MyAzureDbLinkedServer" reported an error. One or more arguments were reported invalid by the provider.
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MyAzureDbLinkedServer" returned message "The parameter is incorrect.".
```

For resolving the issue did all the trick which was found. Some of like...

1. LOCAL DTC Property Security Settings
2. Allow a program through Windows Firewall to enable DTC public private
3. Linked in Server Option : RPC & RPC OUT
4. Turning off firewall
5. Restarted VM

But nothing work so far. does it will not work as Azure Database Service doesn't have MSDTC Service? Is there any other solution for my objective?

Thanks

Comment: Can you execute a sproc over a linked server like that with OPENROWSET? Might be easier just to pull the data to a local db and query it there. Probably better performance too.

Comment: No. OPENROWSET not support in Azure Database Service.

Comment: Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) is not available for Azure SQL Database, which is the reason why the second query is failing. Can you describe your exact goal so that the community can look into alternatives?

Comment: Exact goal is to run SSRS reports without VM (due to costing). As per my knowledge its not possible without VM. So decided use VM very minimum just for SSRS reports and actual database let reside on Azure Database Service. Actual database procedures uses OPENROWSET functions. When pointing SSRS datasource to Actual database its not allowing to generate report due to OPENROWSET error.